# Construct an ordered pair from an undirected graph of unordered pairs?

Tags: graph-theory

Set theory depends on a set membership function which is a class of ordered pairs.  Is it possible to construct the ordered pair from an undirected graph of unordered pairs?  The graph may be traversed from either a start node or optionally any node.

I'm curious how the set membership function could be represented as an undirected graph, which appears to be lower level mathematical structure than a set.

My first idea is a structure as follows.  The top is the start node, depth 1 is the start of a representation of an ordered pair, depth 4 encodes in binary the order, depth 5 is where the horizontal line on the right is and further represents an ordinal number.  My thoughts were this could be used to represent the set membership function instead of the primitive it is typically.

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing the notions of "graph" from math and computer science. Also, graphs are defined using set theory, so the idea that (undirected) graphs are "lower-level" is questionable. It's easier to build symmetric relations (undirected graphs) out of arbitrary relations (directed graphs) than the other way around. Whether it's even possible the other way is an interesting question (and I guess what you mean to ask).

Comment: @Karl the set membership function has as domain and codomain an ordered binary relation of two domains and truth.  Graph adjacency is the same but without the restriction on order of the domains.  Without using set theory, graph  adjacency does appear lower level.  Maybe another question is can a undirected graph be constructed from a directed graph with some bijection?

Comment: The set membership symbol $\in$ is a relation symbol in the underlying logical language that we use to define all other mathematical objects (including graphs and functions), so it's much lower-level. But I think you can ask similar questions at the logic level (about bootstrapping arbitrary relations from symmetric ones) or at the graph level (bootstrapping directed from undirected).

Comment: Here's the logic version: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126844/can-all-relations-be-defined-from-symmetric-relations

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151497/755

Answer (score 1):

Given a directed graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, we can encode $G$ as an undirected graph $H$ with $2n$ vertices and $m $ edges as follows:

- For each vertex $x$ of $G$, include two vertices in $H$ called $a_x$ and $b_x$.
- For each edge $(x,y)$ of $G$, include the edge $\{a_x,b_y\}$ in $H$.

This results in a bipartite undirected graph $H$ where every edge is between the "a" and "b" vertex sets. We can recover $G$ from it by drawing arrowheads on the "b" side and then merging each $\{a_x,b_x\}$ pair into a single vertex $x$.